# Why is my Makefile's target specific variable getting set for all targets?

Tags: variables, makefile

I have a Makefile similar to the following:

```
target1: DEFAULT_VALUE ?= $(shell bash -c 'read -p "Enter DEFAULT_VALUE to set: " value && echo $$value')

target2:
    echo "Hello"

target1:
    echo "World"
```

I expect that the code to set DEFAULT_VALUE will only execute if I run `make target1`, however I find that it runs even if I run `make target2`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your "similar" makefile is not similar enough.  Your example above works fine for me: if I run `make target2` then the shell command is not executed.  If I run `make target1`, then it is.

Please check your example before posting it here and provide one that really fails.

My suspicion is that in your real environment, whatever is represented by `target2` is a prerequisite of whatever is represented by `target1`, which means that `target2` will inherit all of `target1`'s target-specific variable assignments.

Comment: I would say you obviously didn't try it either, since the above Makefile won't run the shell command for either `make target1` or `make target2`...

Comment: Obviously, but clearly the variable WAS being used in the real file, so in my test (which I _did_ run) I added a reference to the variable.  That's easy enough since it's obvious, but once that was done and it worked as expected, there's no way to know in what way the poster's real makefile differed from the example.

Answer (score 0):

With the above Makefile, the shell command will *never* run, for any target.  That's because that style of variable is a recursively expanding variable, so it will be expanded (and the shell command run) every time the variable is *used*.

If you change the last action in the Makefile to

```
target1:
        echo $(DEFAULT_VALUE)
        echo $(DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

then it will run TWICE when you `make target1`, echoing potentially two different things

If you want the shell command to run only once, you need to use `:=` to set it.  But if you do that, it will be run when the Makefile is read (before its even considering which targets to build), so it will run regardless of which target you eventually specify.

If you want something that will only run when a given target is built, you need to put it in the actions for that target.  The easiest way to do that is with a recursive make call

```
target1:
        read -p "Enter DEFAULT_VALUE to set: " value && \
        $(MAKE) real_target1 DEFAULT_VALUE=$$value
```

Comment: None of this has any relevance to the poster's stated issue: he didn't say that it _NEVER_ ran.  He said the script was executed _both_ when he invoked `make target1` and `make target2`.  Recursion could work but the poster's solution of using target-specific variables will work... it _does_ work in my test cases.  There's no reason, given the example we have, to prefer recursion.